# When executing command ethtool -S ethX instead of expected statistics following message is displayed: "no stats available"

Tags: networking, drivers, rhel8, ethtool

It ethtool command only fails on `ethtool -S ethX`.
If I run the command `ethtool -i ethX` it shows the expected data.
This is on RHEL8. It's a known issue apparently, since [Redhat itself has a solution](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/322353), but I need to figure out what the solution is.

Can someone please help me figure out what is causing this?

Comment: what's wrong with the solution you linked to? Doesn't the solution you linked to tell you what the solution is? And why do you need to know the cause as well? Cause and solution are two different things, you can apply a solution without knowing the cause.

Comment: @Jaromanda X, the solution posted is SUBSCRIBER EXCLUSIVE CONTENT, which I cannot access

Comment: oh, I didn't even bother clicking that link, thought there was a solution there, but, if you can't access it, it's not much of a solution